# Make a C static library that only exposes the API

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, ld, objcopy

I have an old static library that includes some functions produced by a C auto-coder (Mathworks/Simulink). I have just made a new static library (that does totally different things from the old library) that uses a newer version of the auto-coder. I need to make an executable that links both these libraries. Unfortunately many of the helper functions generated by the auto-coder have the same name in the old and new libraries but their functionality has changed. These functions are not part of the API. Obviously when I try to link I get complaints that the same symbols appear in both libraries.
The old library is untouchable, but I can mess with the new one.

The libraries are built with

```
gcc -c *.c  
ar -crs libwhatever.a *.o
```

and linked with

```
gcc main.o -L. -lold -lnew
```

My current solution is to look at all the symbol clashes given by gcc and rename the symbols in the new library using

```
objcopy --redefine-sym sym=sym_new libnew.a
```

This seems to work. My program links and behaves as expected. But I'm wondering if it is the right/best thing to do.

Ideally I'd like to make a libnew.a that only exposes the API functions and nothing else. That way I guarantee no symbol clashes when I try to link. Is this possible I cannot figure out how.

Please note that I have little previous experience in these matters. Also, if it's relevant/not obvious, I'm using Linux.

**Edit**

Below is a rather contrived minimal working example.

old/printOld.c:

```
#include "printOld.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void printOld()
{
  printStr();
}

void printStr()
{
  printf("Old\n");
}
```

old/printOld.h:

```
void printStr();
```

old/buildOld:

```
gcc -c printOld.c
ar -crs libold.a printOld.o
```

new/printNew.c:

```
#include "printNew.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void printNew()
{
  printStr();
}

void printStr()
{
  printf("New\n");
}
```

new/printNew.h:

```
void printStr();
```

new/buildNew:

```
gcc -c printNew.c
ar -crs libnew.a printNew.o

#objcopy --redefine-sym printStr=printStrNew libnew.a
```

main/main.c:

```
void printOld();
void printNew();

int main()
{
  printOld();
  printNew();

  return 0;
}
```

main/buildMain:

```
gcc main.c -L../old -L../new -lold -lnew
```

The linker error when I leave objcopy commented out is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../new/libnew.a(printNew.o): in function `printStr':
printNew.c:(.text+0x11): multiple definition of `printStr'; ../old/libold.a(printOld.o):printOld.c:(.text+0x11): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The above example has the same kind of structure as the auto-generated code. I know that I can fix my problem by declaring the functions in the header files as static, but I'd rather not have to mess with the auto-generated code. It is very large and very unpleasant.

Comment: To help us help you, please provide a [mre]. Yes, this could include writing sources for both libraries by hand, and an application. But "minimal" means that the minimum suffices, for example two functions per library. -- I don't understand why/how you receive double symbol errors. The linker commonly only adds modules that resolve still unresolved references. That's why I think we need the example.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the minimal working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use --keep-global-symbol=symbolname option with objcopy:

```
objcopy --keep-global-symbol=printOld libold.a
```

or

```
objcopy --keep-global-symbols=api libold.a
```

where *api* is a file with a list of API functions